# Finding the derivative $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2 -9}$,

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, fractions

I need to find the slope at a=5, using the definition for the function $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2 -9}$,

$$f'(x) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} {f(x+\Delta x)\over \Delta x}$$

The answer book says the slope is ${1\over 4}$

Here's what I did,

$$f'(x) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} {(\sqrt{(x+\Delta x)^2 -9} - \sqrt {x^2 -9} )(\sqrt{(x+\Delta x)^2 -9}+ \sqrt{x^2-9)})\over\Delta x(\sqrt{(x+\Delta x)^2 -9}+ \sqrt{x^2-9)}}
(1)\\=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} {(x+\Delta x)^2 -9 -x^2 +9\over \Delta x(\sqrt{(x+\Delta x)^2 -9}+ \sqrt{x^2-9)}}
(2)\\=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}{x^2 +2x \Delta x+ \Delta x^2 -x^2\over\Delta x(\sqrt{(x+\Delta x)^2 -9}+ \sqrt{x^2-9)}}
(3)\\=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}{2x\Delta x +\Delta x^2\over\Delta x(\sqrt{(x+\Delta x)^2 -9}+ \sqrt{x^2-9)}}
(4)\\=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} {2x+\Delta x\over(\sqrt{(x+\Delta x)^2 -9}+ \sqrt{x^2-9)}}
(5)\\={2x\over \sqrt{x^2-9+x^2-9}}
(6)\\={2x\over2 \sqrt{x^2 -9}}
(7)\\={x\over \sqrt {x^2 -9}} (8)$$

Now I substitute 5, and I don't get 1/4!!

What have I done wrong??

Thanks

Comment: You have asked several similar questions already. Let's take a break. In every question, it's because you made a simply arithmetic error. Perhaps explore one answer and work your other problems more carefully before asking yet another almost identical question.

Comment: Your calculation was fine, and then there were a couple of algebra errors in a row. As a minor suggestion, since we are interested in $x=5$, it might have been a good idea not to proceed "generally," but instead to use $x=5$ from the beginning.

Comment: @Arkamis I don't see a problem with the user asking the questions he/she did.  If it bothers you that their mistakes are arithmetic, maybe you should move on.  Unless the user is violating StackExchange rules, it isn't for any of us to tell them what questions they can and can't ask.

Comment: @user46944 It is generally frowned-upon on this site to rapidly and serially ask questions that are abstract duplicates.

Comment: @Arkamis Is it against the StackExchange terms of use?  Or the rules?  If not, we have no place telling users how they can and can't use the site.

Comment: (Cont.) So there were errors. But in fact the slope is not $\frac{1}{4}$, so there is also an error in the answer file.

Comment: @user46944 There is a difference between "terms of use" and "community standards." There is also a difference between "telling users what to do" and "suggesting that they take more care in solving problems to avoid catchable errors."

Comment: @Arkamis Maybe as their questions are answered on here, and they realize their mistakes, they will naturally begin to realize that they need to be careful.  I think that is more likely to happen than them realizing it by being told to be more careful and stop asking their questions here.

Comment: @user46944 Perhaps you should read what I initially wrote more carefully. I didn't tell the OP to stop asking questions. I suggested to take a break and examine the errors caught in his other questions -- which is a suggestion that I made for the OP's benefit.

Comment: Sorry, @Arkamis It's just that I don't have tutor anymore that I have hard time teaching my self from a book, and since the book had several wrong answers, I'm curiously asking more than before.

Comment: @Arkamis "You have asked several questions already.  Let's take a break."  That is telling the user to stop.

Comment: @user46944 Perhaps you should read the *entirety* of my comment.

Comment: @didgocks That's fine, and it can be frustrating when the answer key is wrong. But I've read all your other questions and most of the time it's because you made a simple and common mistake. I'd suggest working through each solution twice, because your frustration might be causing you to make these errors -- I'm speaking from first-hand experience here! If you work through a problem more than once, you're more likely to pick up on the mistake.

Comment: @Arkamis I read it, but I didn't quote the entire thing because there is no need.  The entire comment suggests the user should stop (even temporarily) asking the questions they are asking and figure it out on their own.  I don't agree with telling the user is.  I agree with your suggestion that the user should try to solve the problem multiple times on their own, but I took issue with the "take a break" comment because I see it as crossing the line from being helpful to speaking authoritatively.  Anyway, I don't want this to turn into an endless argument.  Let's just agree to disagree.

Comment: @user46944 Do not blame me for your inference of "let's take a break" to mean "stop" and not "let's take a break and evaluate what you've already done," because I literally explained "break" to mean "pause and reflect." But I agree, let's take a break from this one-sided discussion.

Answer (score 2):

(5)to (6) step  !!!you have error $$\sqrt{(x+\Delta x)^2-9}+\sqrt{(x)^2-9} \neq \sqrt{(x)^2-9+(x)^2-9} $$in fact  $$\sqrt{a+b} \neq \sqrt{a} +\sqrt{b}$$

Answer (score 1):

In step 6, the denominator should be $2 \sqrt{x^2-9}$.

Comment: Also, are you sure the book's answer is $\frac{1}{4}$? It should be $\frac{5}{4}$.

Comment: Well, the book had couple mistakes in the answer book before...

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2-9}+\sqrt{x^2-9}=2\sqrt{x^2-9}$.